# Swapping two variables with RegEx

Tags: php, regex

So here is my code, and then I will explain what I am having trouble with:

```
foreach($people as $person){
    // counter for each person
    $counter = 0;
    // get variables for each item
    list($fullName,$phoneNumber,$address,$birthday,$salary) = explode(':', $person);
    // get variables for first and last name
    list($firstName, $lastName) = explode(" ", $fullName);
    // get variables for phone numbers
    list($areaCode, $middleDigits, $lastDigits) = explode('-',$phoneNumber);
    //get variables for address
    list($street,$city,$statezip) = explode(", ", $address);
    // get variables for state and zip separately
    list($state,$zipCode) = explode(" ", $statezip);


    // print file with the first and last names reversed
    $tempFName = $firstName;
    $tempLName = $lastName;
    echo $newPerson = (preg_replace("/($tempLName)($tempFName)/", $firstName, $lastName, $person))."<br/>";

    $counter++;
}
```

What I want to do, is print the original $person, but with the $firstName and $lastName 's reversed.  I'm able to replace the values and then print out each variable, but then it wouldn't have the same format as $person originally did unless I formatted each line.  I was wondering if there was a way to do it without formatting each output to look identical to the original $person variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if Firstname and Lastname are always separated by whitespace and preceed the first colon character... if this is correct the above may be overkill. Try this:

```
echo $newPerson = (preg_replace("/(.*?)\s+(.*?)\:/", '$2,$1:', $person))."<br/>";
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  Would you mind explaining the regex you wrote there?  Also the $2,$1?  Thanks again.

Comment: In regular expressions, parentheses define groups which can be referenced later using the dollar sign. In this case the left-most parentheses group was matching firstname, and the second group matching last name. \s matches any whitespace character, and the plus sign says to continue to match it even if it repeats. The forward-slash \: means to literally match a colon, because the colon could be meaningful in preg. Finally, the `$2,$1:` is to output our match - lastname first; followed by a comma and the firstname - and then replacing the colon that we matched. I hope that helps!

Comment: Forward-slashes aren't easy to mark as code with a back-tick on Stack!